# В чем смысл команды grep \~ |tr -d \~

Tags: unix, grep

```
cat $something |  grep \~ |tr -d \~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `cat $something |  grep \~ | tr -d \~`

это запуск трёх программ «конвейером».

1. `cat $something` — выдать в *stdout* содержимое файла, имя которого содержится в переменной `$something`
2. `grep \~` — отфильтровать строки, поступающие в *stdin* программы *grep*, передав в *stdout* только те, что содержат символ `~`
3. `tr -d \~` — удалить из поступающих в *stdin* строк символ `~`

---

почему `\~`, а не просто `~`? для того, чтобы программа, в которой выполняется команда (т.н. «оболочка», «shell») не заменила символ `~` на содержимое переменной окружения `$HOME` (путь к домашнему каталогу пользвателя, выполнившего команду). с таким же успехом можно было заключить символ `~` в кавычки, одинарные либо двойные: `'~'` или `"~"`

---

доп. чтение:

```
$ man cat
$ man grep
$ man tr
$ man $SHELL
```